# How to make WooCommerce multiple filter with custom meta fields

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to create a big filter for shop page and can't find anything about this.

I created some meta fields for product data inside general by hooking inside `woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data`.

So for example, I created 2 select meta fields:

1) with two options, let's call it `A` and `B`;

2) with two options, let's call it `X` and `Y`;

Now what I want, when user go to my shop page, he will see 2 dropdowns,
choose, for example, in first dropdown `A` and in the second `X` then click button "search" and get all products, which has these metas.

Is it possible? I can't find anything, maybe I'm googling stupidly.

I even tried to find ready plugins,
But all I've found is ajax filter plugins, but that's not what I want.

Sorry for my English, thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally the way to do this in WooCommerce is to use product attributes and the built in filter widgets.

Comment: @JacobPeattie what about meta fields like numbers, checkboxes? can they be filtered by attributes properly?